# get xml elements using attributes value

Tags: php, xml, attributes

I have this xml with me.
What I need to do is to get the name and visiturl using the attributes hard coded id. I do not want it in a loop. I just need to print `name` whose `id=3`.

I know I can use foreach and get all the data or I can get the first id using:

```
$op = simplexml_load_file($file);
echo $op->urldata[0]->url->attributes(); //print 1 gets the first id.
```

Checked some example [in php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php), but cant find exacty what I am looking for. I tried:

```
echo $op->urldata[0]->url->attributes()->{'1'}->name; //prints nothing
```

Is this possible to get what I want directly?

```
<urldata>
    <url id="1">
        <name>Google</name>
        <visiturl>www.google.com</visiturl>
    </url>
    <url id="2">
        <name>Google1</name>
        <visiturl>www.google1.com</visiturl>
    </url>
    <url id="3">
        <name>Google2</name>
        <visiturl>www.google2.com</visiturl>
    </url>
    <url id="4">
        <name>Google3</name>
        <visiturl>www.google3.com</visiturl>
    </url>
    <url id="5">
        <name>Google4</name>
        <visiturl>www.google4.com</visiturl>
    </url>
</urldata>
```

Comment: `echo $op->xpath('//url[@id="3"]/name/text()')[0];`

Comment: Thanks I got the value but how slow is xpath as compared to using $op->url[2]->name;

Comment: @Arjun test it and tell us

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try

```
echo $op->xpath('//url[@id="3"]/name/text()')[0];
```

(Credits for this go to @splash58)

You might want to read this xpath tutorial on [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_intro.asp). This really helped me a lot.